# Output of `java -version` not matched by grep or awk

Tags: linux, grep, awk, ksh

On my Linux machine, it isn't clear to me why if I do the following then I don't get only the version string ("1.5.0_32").

```
# java -version | grep version | awk '{print $NF}'
java version "1.5.0_32"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_32-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 1.5.0_32-b05, mixed mode)
```

Why don't `grep` or `awk` work?

Just to show that grep and awk work on other example

```
# echo ' java version "1.5.0_32" ' | grep version  | awk '{print $NF}'
"1.5.0_32"
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try like this:

```
java -version 2>&1 | grep version  | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Looks like the output is going to stderr.

Also, grep is not needed:

```
java -version 2>&1 | awk '/version/{print $NF}'
```